# Was Boba Fett the first clone?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, attack-of-the-clones, boba-fett, the-bad-batch

It is established in AotC that Boba Fett is an "unaltered" clone of Jango - that is, he ages normally.  By this logic, is Boba the first clone?  Since he's around 10 in AotC, he must've been aging naturally for some time.  Is there explicit confirmation that Boba was the first-ever Jango Fett clone made on Kamino?

*The Bad Batch spoilers*

> In the most recent TBB episode, where Omega is revealed to be a genetic sibling to Boba Fett, it is also said that Boba's name on Kamino was "Alpha."  This does seem to lend credence to him being the first clone.

Canon and/or Legends answers are accepted!

Comment: Good question! Boba was also part of Jango's payment, which he may have demanded up front!

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that Boba was born/cloned in 32BBY - the same year that cloning started, so it stands to reason that Boba could be one of the first batch, if not _the_ first clone. It might also be worth mentioning that in production of any product, there is often several test and prototypes before a production model is made, so Boba may have been one of the first successful production models, and then after Boba had been born the Kaminoans started to speed up the development/growth process (cut waste, increase profit)

Comment: Do you require a canon answer, or are you interested in a Legends answer?

Comment: @Null I'll take either!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Boba is the first clone

> Although he was born a clone, Alpha regarded Jango as his father, who likewise viewed the boy as his son.[14] Soon after referred to as Boba,[13] he was the first of many clones modeled on the Jango Fett template, but was only one of two known clones that were a pure genetic copy of the original Fett template, the other being Omega.[15]

Source:https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Boba_Fett

Comment: "he was the first of many clones modeled on the Jango Fett template" but was he the _first_ clone?

Comment: Slight specification error, he was the first Clone not the first clone, i.e, he was the first of the Clones who fought in the clone wars, but no the first clone made by the Kaminoan; Bad Batch seems to imply that the Kaminoans tried cloning themselves first (the question asked implies they're only talking about the Clone clones not just clones in general)

Answer (score 9):

**Canon:** Yes, according to a 2015 Topps trading card (emphasis added):

[image: Back side of Topps trading card]

> Boba Fett
>
> Jango Fett Clone
>
> A bounty hunter dressed in Mandalorian armor like his father figure. Boba Fett is a clone of Jango Fett, created shortly after the Battle of Naboo as **the first of many Fett replicas** designed to become part of the Republic's Grand Army. As a youngster, Boba enjoys the combat training and danger-filled life his parent provides, and is suspicious when Obi-Wan Kenobi visits their home in Kamino seeking information. Soon after they flee to Geonosis, young Fett is horrified to see Jango slain in the arena by a Lightsaber-wielding Mace Windu.

Source: [Star Wars: Card Trader wiki](https://starwarscardtrader.fandom.com/wiki/Boba_Fett_-_Jango_Fett_Clone_-_Base_Series_1)

Answer (score 6):

In Legends, **Boba was not the first clone**. The first Fett clones were the [Null-class Advanced Recon Commandos](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Null-class_Advanced_Recon_Commando), a cohort of six genetically *enhanced* clones (Boba was of course unmodified, and most of the clones were modified to be more docile).